# find matching values in 2 different columns in 2 different excel file

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Hi new to vba in excel 2007

Here is the scenario I want to write a macro where a value in column A from abc.xls is in column c from .xyz.xls. If someone can help me out with this logic and can easily finish the rest. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can do this easily using vlookup() - no need for VBA.  Unless your need is more complex than your question makes it seem...

Comment: Loop through cells in ColA - use Find() on ColC to locate any matching row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.  Going on what Tim said in his comment `vlookup()` is an easy way to find a value in another sheet.  In your case the function would look something like this:

```
vlookup([abc.xls]Sheet1!A1, [xyz.xls]Sheet1!C:C, 1, False)
```

The first part is the value to look up, the second part is the table to look for the value in (in our case only the one row), the third part is which column of the table to return the value from, and the third part tells it to find an exact match.  So this function will look for the value in A1 of abc.xls in column C of xyz.xls and return that value if it finds it.

If you instead want the row where the value was found use the match function.

```
match([abc.xls]Sheet1!A1, [xyz.xls]Sheet1!C:C, 0)
```

This will do the same thing as vlookup but return the row where it found the match instead.

Note that you don't have to type these formulas in directly.  If you navigate to a new workbook and select the cell it should generate the reference just as if you had selected one from the current sheet.

Comment: Thank you and that is useful but I am going to need it in vba because there are going to be other features being added to the macro.

Comment: If this is what you need you can use `WorksheetFunction.Match` or `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to use them from a macro.